# Java 8 Unreachable Code

Tags: java, java-8, unreachable-code

I am fairly new to Java and I ran into this problem once or twice in one of my books. This is a super simple program and I just don't understand why it's not working. I know when you use return, anything after it in the method is meaningless. So does this mean after you perform an for statement or an if statement that is a return?

I am using Java 8 on Windows 8 in the latest version of Eclipse.

This is my simple program:

```
// Find the sum of 1 through 50 and the average.

class SumAndAverage
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int sum = 0;
        double average = 0;
        for(int i = 1; 1 <= 50; i++)
        {
            sum += i;
        }

// the following code is "unreachable"
        average = sum / 100;

        System.out.println("The sum is: " + sum);
        System.out.println("The average is " + average);
    }
}
```

Comment: Voting to close for typo. `1 <= 50` will always be true.

Comment: Shouldn't average be `sum / 50`?

Comment: Everyone has been fantastic. After view I realized I had a few typographical errors, and I apologize for that. It was a simple fix, but I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`1` is always less than or equal to `50`, isn't it? You probably meant to compare `i` with `50`:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 50; i++)
{
    sum += i;
}
```

Comment: Once I replaced 1 with i, that fixed the problem. Thank you so much.

Comment: Wow, if I had just told him how to fix it, I could have received 6 upvotes. :(

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 1; 1 <= 50; i++)
```

1 is always less than or equal to 50.